# Advice on Parsing EXCEL file to creat new EXCEL file

Tags: vba, excel

I am seeking some advice to get started writing code to parse excel files and create a new file with rebuilt worksheets, if anyone could be kind enough the respond with advice it would be greatly appreciated.  I am not looking for anyone to write my code but I sure would like thoughts on how to do this.  It seems like nested loops might be the trick or maybe array?

I have files in a directory that all have the same record structure but if a record has more than one variable the source makes a new row instead of appending the variable horizontally across the first row of the record.  I would like my data to run horizontally like a normal excel spreadsheet.

I would like column L to define the worksheets.  There are only five different values in column L.

In the source file columns G, K, and L are key columns to determine a record.  If a row and row + 1 have the same G, K, and L values then row + 1, column N should go to row, column O.  Then if row and row + 2 have the same G, K, and L values then row + 2, column N should go to row, column P.  Etc.

If G, K, and L don't match then row is finished and row + n becomes a new row.

here is my data logic

```
Open c:\xml\vac\values00.xls
First_Row = 3
Last_Row = Last_Row

For First_Row to Last_Row
    Read First_Row
        Get Column_A
        Get Column_B
        Get Column_C
        Get Column_D
        Get Column_E
        Get Column_F
        Get Column_G 'critical
        Get Column_H
        Get Column_I
        Get Column_J
        Get Column_K 'critical
        Get Column_L 'critical
        Get Column_M
        Get Column_N

    'build row          
    New_First_Row = Column_A, Column_B, Column_C, Column_D, Column_E, Column_F, Column_G, Column_H, Column_I, Column_J, Column_K, Column_L, Column_M, Column_N

    'write row to worksheet defined by value in Column L
    Write New_First_Row to Column_L_worksheet

    'read next row and check L, K, and G, if they match previous L, K, and G then same record, move N to New_First_Row O
    Next_Row = First_Row + 1
    Next_Column = Column N
    For Next_Row to Last_Row
        Next_Column = Next_Column + 1
            Read Next_Row
                Get Column_Ln
                Get Column_Kn
                Get Column_Gn
            If (Column_L = Column_Ln) AND (Column_K = Column_Kn) AND (Column_G = Column_Gn)
                Then 'grow horizontally
                Get Column_N
                Write Column_N to Next_Column
            End IF
    Next 'new row

Next First_Row
```

Answer (score 0):

You may actually have better success with this using VBSCRIPT. It sounds like you need to loop through some files in a directory, and then loop through the rows of the excel files in that directory.

I have blogged about how to do each on my site:

[VBSCRIPT - Loop through all files in a directory](https://seanwoodward-public.sharepoint.com/Blog/Post/13/VBSCRIPT-%E2%80%93-Loop-through-all-files-in-a-directory)

[VBSCRIPT - Loop through all rows in an excel sheet](https://seanwoodward-public.sharepoint.com/Blog/Post/17/VBSCRIPT-%E2%80%93-Loop-through-All-Rows-in-an-Excel-Worksheet)

The two scripts can be combined similar to the below:

```
'Declare variables to be used  
Dim oFSO  
Dim myFolder  
Dim myDirectoryName
Dim myConnectionString
Dim myConnection
Dim myRS

'Define variables  
'Access a Scripting.FileSystemObject  
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  

'Get the current directory of the script file  
myDirectoryName = get_Current_Directory  

'Set the current directory to a folder object  
Set myFolder = oFSO.GetFolder( myDirectoryName )  

'Loop through each of the files in the folder  
For each myFile in myFolder.Files  

    'Check if its an excel file
    If LCase(oFSO.GetExtensionName( myFile.Path )) = "xlsx" Then

        Set myConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        Set myRS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

        'Open the excel file
        myConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & myFile.Path & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"
        myConnection.Open myConnectionString

        myRS.Open "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", myConnection

        Do While Not myRS.eof

            Set myFields = myRS.Fields

            For each myField in myFields

                wscript.echo myField.Name & ": " & myField.Value

            Next

            myRS.MoveNext

        Loop

        'Cleanup
        Set myRS = Nothing
        Set myConnection = Nothing      

    End If

Next  

Function get_Current_Directory()  
    Dim oFSO  
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  
    get_Current_Directory = oFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(".")  
End Function
```

Save this script as a .VBS file in the same directory where you have these files and then go in to a command prompt. Change directories to where this vbs file is saved and then execute `cscript myscript.vbs` at the command prompt and the script will loop through all of the excel files in the directory and output the contents to the console. This will at least show you how to loop through all of the files and all of the data in the files. The rest is up to you as far as how you want to handle them.

Thanks,

Sean W.

Comment: Thank-you for your response/solution.  I am off to do some reading and understanding, vbscript looks difficult.